# Is this tile installed correctly?

Tags: tile

[image: wood look floor tile installation]

Hi,  I asked my installer to install these 6" X 24" tiles with a 6" offset and laid to look like a wood floor (random look).    This is what I got. Do you think I am unreasonable in asking the installer to remove the floor and replace it?

Comment: speaking pedantically, did you want a 6" offset or a (random look)?  Those are almost opposite words and I can empathize with the installer not doing what you wanted, since I'm not sure what you mean either.  They should have asked you before they started and you should have been more precise (diagrams are great!).

Answer (score 4):

If you explicitly stated you wanted the tile seams to be random, then no, it's not unreasonable to ask them to redo it.

That said, at 24", I don't think you'd actually like the look. That's a really short tile for random joints. Note that actual hardwood floors not only have random seams, but random lengths of boards. Even engineered wood at typically 4' lengths can look a little odd when you try to emulate the random seams of actual hardwood flooring.

FWIW, I actually like how it was laid. So maybe compromise and ask for a % off the bill?

Comment: Always try for a percentage off if not what expected. If the 6" offset was the only statement, and random not mentioned, then the installer did his interpretation of a 6" offset. My understanding, on just reading the request would have been a 6" step on each tile, like stair step joints. Hardly random looking either.... It does look good.

Comment: Agree that it looks good... though a 6" stair step could have been okay too. I doubt that anyone could do good looking "random" with 2' sections.